# How to customize a tikz picture

Tags: tikz-pgf

How to remove the rectange who surrounds the `A character` and to draw that char vertically, please ?

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,calc,positioning,decorations.pathreplacing,matrix}

\begin{document}   

\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration={brace}][scale=2] 
\node [draw] (A) {A}; 
\node [fit=(A)] (fit) {};              
\draw [decorate,line width=1pt] 
  ([yshift=-5pt]fit.south west) -- ([yshift=5pt]fit.north west);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What do you mean by "draw that char vertically,". Do something like `\node [scale=2] (A) {A};`.

Comment: @HarishKumar, to draw it translated by 90° .

Comment: You want to rotate the brace too?

Comment: Don't say `draw` if you don't want it to draw the node i.e. a box around it. Just say e.g. `\node (A) {A};`. Do you mean you want the A *horizontally*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To suppress the rectangle, delete the `draw` option; to rotate the node contents, use the `rotate=<angle>` option:

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,calc,positioning,decorations.pathreplacing,matrix}

\begin{document}   

\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration={brace},scale=2] 
\node [rotate=90] (A) {A}; 
\node [fit=(A)] (fit) {};              
\draw [decorate,line width=1pt] 
  ([yshift=-5pt]fit.south west) -- ([yshift=5pt]fit.north west);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As in your other question, it's still not clear to me why you use the `fit` node and the remarks I made about using two optional arguments and the `scale` option.